# UITableView in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` whose all cells contains a `UITableView`. My `UICollectionView` delegate / datasource methods are handled by a view controller (let's say `TTCollectionViewController`), and `tableViews` are handled directly by `collection view cells` (`TTCollectionViewCell`).

In order to change some label colors, I need to keep track of each selected rows on my tableViews so i did something like that :

```
//
// TTCollectionViewCell.m
//
[...]
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // keep track of selected drugs
    if (![self.selectedDrugIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [self.selectedDrugIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        TTTableViewCell *contentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"test"];
        if (contentCell == nil)
            contentCell = [[TTTableViewCell alloc] init];

        [...]

        // test
        if ([self.selectedDrugIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
            contentCell.drugLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        } else {
            contentCell.drugLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
}
[...]
```

But here's the thing : with the dequeue reusable thing, my `collectionView` is messing up all my tracks (on scrolling, selected rows on table 1 become selected on table 3 for example).

I know it's a bad idea to don't use `dequeuereusable` (i don't even know if it's possible to not use it), but is there something similar that i can do ?

Do anyone have already implement this kind of case ?

Thx in advance.

EDIT :

Here's my `cellForRow...` methods of my collectionView as you asked for :

```
///
/// TTCollectionController.m
///
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TTCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.data = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The older style deque is still available for this kind of case, so I think that's okay.  I see nothing wrong with this - albeit unusual - code.  I think the problem lies in your collection view cellForItem method, making sure there that the dequed cell get's the right model every time.  Can you post that code?

Comment: Thx for your reply. I edited my post with the `cellForItem` method of my collection view